# Error: Code too Large in Generated Java File

Tags: java, midi

I'm coding a Java application that reads a .MID file and generates a .java(wich when compiled and executed generates a .wav file), however, the generated .java file cointains a very large constructor method, so the generated code won't compile. I'm aware of the maximum size of 64kb for each method, but is there a way to change it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any reason to be generating a java file?

Comment: Can't you split it into several files?

Comment: Just doing it as a exercise to learn better about Java Sound MCMastery. I tried with some smaller MIDIs to see if it worked and it works. The thing now will be split it in smaller methods like dorukayhan suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your app break down the constructor into several methods - that is, the constructor calls multiple small methods to do its job. This also makes debugging easier as fixing bugs scattered across methods one method at a time is more of a piece of cake rather than dealing with a huge, broken method.

Here's an example of a method (not necessarily a constructor, in fact you can break down all kinds of methods) broken down into smaller methods:

```
public int doLotsOfStuff(String arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, BiFunction<Boolean, String, Integer> arg3){
    arg0 = reverse(arg0);
    foo(arg1, arg2);
    return bar(arg0, Integer.valueOf(arg1), arg2, arg3);
}

String reverse(String arg0){
    StringBuilder foobar = new StringBuilder(arg0);
    foobar.reverse();
    return foobar.toString();
}

void foo(int arg0, boolean arg1){
    System.out.println(arg1 ? ~arg0 : arg0);
}

<A, B> int bar(String arg0, A arg1, B arg2, BiFunction<B, String, A> arg3){
    return String.valueOf(arg3.apply(arg2, arg1)).concat(arg0).hashCode();
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated point, may everyone **not** question the overall sanity of the things `doLotsOfStuff` does?

Comment: I tested with some smaller MIDIs to see if it worked. It indeed works. I will try changing the app to split the generated methods like this, thanks!